# SimpleAudioIndexer. Generating time-aligned text tags from audio file gives an error: ERROR: "cmd_ln.c", line 942: Unknown argument: -alignctl

Tags: python, pocketsphinx, sphinx4

I used the code below to generate time aligned text file from audio file. For that purpose, I installed SimpleAudioIndexer library. Also, I installed the required libraries by following this guide at https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/training-custom-speech-to-text-model-using-cmu-sphinx4-part-1-setting-up-cmu-sphinx-c90123c9d7ac.

```
from SimpleAudioIndexer import SimpleAudioIndexer as sai
indexer = sai(mode="cmu",src_dir="/home/hbtousa/Python")
print("indexer..", indexer)
indexer.index_audio(basename = "speech.wav")
indexer.save_indexed_audio("{}/indexed_audio".format(indexer.src_dir))
indexer.load_indexed_audio("{}/indexed_audio".format(indexer.src_dir))
print(indexer.get_timestamps())
```

I have no issues with the install on my ubuntu 20.04 linux machine. I have issues with the result which ended on an error and I could fetch the txt file with the results.

Error Message

```
ERROR: "cmd_ln.c", line 942: Unknown argument: -alignctl
```

[image: Error Message]

Full Results
[image: Full Results]

Comment: This other project has a solution for this error, maybe it would work for you? https://github.com/antiboredom/audiogrep#troubleshooting "`uninstalling and reinstalling cmu-sphinxbase and cmu-pocketsphinx may solve the issue.`" So, maybe uninstalling and reinstalling `sphinx4` and `pocketsphinx` would work? That Medium article was written in October 2020, and the SimpleAudioIndexer library was last updated in December 2020, so they're not that old but something might have changed in the interim. The [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/aalireza/SimpleAudioIndexer) might help too.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will give it a try; perhaps, a fresh install might clear the way.